# Decorating a rollover toolbar button with JLayer paints its border

Tags: java, swing, button, toolbar, jlayer

I'm attempting to wrap a `JButton` with a `JLayer` to add some effects/functionality to it. When I replace the button with the wrapper in a toolbar, it paints a button border for some reason. The toolbar has rollover set to `true`.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

```java
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class JLayerButton extends JFrame {

    private JToolBar toolbar;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;

    public JLayerButton() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("JLayer Button");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.setFloatable(false);
        toolbar.setRollover(true);
        getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        button1 = new JButton("One");
        button1.setFocusable(false);
        toolbar.add(button1);
        button2 = new JButton("Two");
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        toolbar.add(button2);
        button3 = new JButton("Three");
        button3.setFocusable(false);
        toolbar.add(button3);

        // wrap button2 in JLayer
        int componentIndex = toolbar.getComponentIndex(button2);
        JButtonLayerUI layerUI = new JButtonLayerUI();
        JLayer<JButton> layer = new JLayer<JButton>(button2, layerUI);
        layer.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
        layer.setFocusable(false);
        toolbar.add(layer, componentIndex);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, 
            IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JLayerButton().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class JButtonLayerUI extends LayerUI<JButton> {

        public JButtonLayerUI() {
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            super.paint(g, c);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JButton> l) {
            onMouseEvent(l, e);
        }

        @Override
        protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JButton> l) {
            onMouseEvent(l, e);
        }

        private void onMouseEvent(JLayer<? extends JButton> l, MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to achieve doesn't seem possible with `JLayer`, since :

From the code of `BasicToolBarUI`, we can see those calls

`installRolloverBorders` is called to install borders on the `JToolBar` :

```
public void setRolloverBorders( boolean rollover ) {
        rolloverBorders = rollover;

        if ( rolloverBorders )  {
            installRolloverBorders( toolBar );
        } else  {
            installNonRolloverBorders( toolBar );
        }
    }
```

`installRolloverBorders` calls `setBorderToRollover` on each of the **direct** `JComponent` childs (non recursive) of the toolbar

```
protected void installRolloverBorders ( JComponent c )  {
        // Put rollover borders on buttons
        Component[] components = c.getComponents();

        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JComponent) {
                ((JComponent) component).updateUI();
                setBorderToRollover(component);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, `setBorderToRollover` will only work on instances of `AbstractButton`, which your `JLayer` is not. So the original borders of your JLayer's buttons are not affected at all.

```
protected void setBorderToRollover(Component c) {
        if (c instanceof AbstractButton) {
            AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton)c;

            Border border = borderTable.get(b);
            if (border == null || border instanceof UIResource) {
                borderTable.put(b, b.getBorder());
            }

            // Only set the border if its the default border
            if (b.getBorder() instanceof UIResource) {
                b.setBorder(getRolloverBorder(b));
            }

            rolloverTable.put(b, b.isRolloverEnabled()?
                              Boolean.TRUE: Boolean.FALSE);
            b.setRolloverEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

To sum it up, the *rollover* effect will only work on components meeting both of those conditions :

1. Be a **direct** child of the `JToolBar`
2. Be an instance of `AbstractButton`

You probably could roll your own version of `BasicToolBarUI` and override some methods to add recursivity for instance, see if it is worth the time.

Comment: I see. This explains the why. I guess I'll just have to live with that border. Extending `BasicToolBarUI` would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes it may have side effects on other parts, you're right.